# Command for inserting for-statement skeleton

Tags: functions

How would one write a function that one could bind to, say, SUPER-f, which inserts the code:

```
for () {
}
```

in the buffer with my cursor being moved into the () parens for filling out the loop guard?

Comment: Have you already heard about [yasnippet](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Yasnippet)?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Didn't try much of anything, since my knowledge of emacs is limited to what's builtin. However, I had not heard of yasnippet and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: @eof: if yasnippet solved your problem, please post an answer to your own question that details the solution, and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd do it like this:

```
(define-skeleton my-for-statement
  "Insert a for () {...} skeleton."
  nil
  \n "for () {" \n > _ "}" \n)
```

The `\n` are for "newlines" (and the ones at beg/end are only added if needed).  The `_` basically says that if you have selected a region before running the command, then this region will end up right where `_` is (IOW, the region will be wrapped by the "for" statement).  And the `>` in front causes this region (if any) to be re-indented.

You can then do `M-x my-for-statement` and that will insert the statement.